# mysqli_num_row erro

Tags: mysqli

Não estou conseguindo mostrar a contagem de colunas no banco de dados. Por exemplo eu quero mostrar no painel, quantos pedidos estão cadastrados. Para isto eu quero a contagem do ID.

```
include 'conexao.php';
$pedidosq = "SELECT id FROM pedido";
$pedidos = mysqli_num_rows($pedidosq);
```

Para exibir dou um echo,

```
<?php  echo $pedidos ?>
```

No entanto, nada aparece. A conexão com o banco de dados está Ok.

Answer (score 0):

Em $pedidosq você apenas está adicionando uma String para a variavel, você precisa executar a query no banco para conseguir obter os resultados e capturar a quantidade de linhas a partir do resultado.

```
$pedidosq = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT id FROM pedido");
$pedidos = $pedidosq -> num_rows;
echo $pedidos;
```

Comment: Exatamente. Eu percebi imediatamente após a postagem. Corrigi e está perfeito. Obrigado!